# Finding a generator of an elliptic curve effectively with huge numbers

Tags: elliptic-curves

In cryptography I am facing the issue to find a generator of some elliptic curve given only the curve over given field and number of elements that the curve has.

The numbers used are enormous so I am struggling to implement any offered scenario how to find generator of an elliptic curve here in stackexchange. If anyone can help I would be thankful.

Comment: What's the background of this? If the field is known then my first point of action was to try and see if it matches a known/named curve.

Comment: HINT: If you find a point on the curve, there's a pretty good chance it's a generator. How would you find a point? How would you check if it's a generator?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes there is no background this is the assignment to do it with Python code.

Comment: @DanielS but the number of points on a curve is x10^70+ so I think that would not be good approach. I know general rule that when the order of an elliptic curve is m, a point P is a generator if, and only if for all divisors d of m , dP ≠ 0 and mP = 0